# Third type of jdbc driver(through intermeditae server). How does it work?

Tags: java, database, api, jdbc, middleware

I have read following article:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/driver-types.html#type-3-jdbc-driver

I didn't understand third type of jdbc driver.

[image]

What the intermediate server?  Is it part of my implementation or this server supply with driver or maybe with database?

I cannot find this driver type for MS SQL or MySql and thus I cannot try to use it.

Comment: @duffymoI didn't want to use this driver I just want to understand principle of operation

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a [type-3 driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_3_Driver_-_Network-Protocol_Driver.28MiddleWare_Driver.29). The intermediate server (or MiddleWare) is part of the type-3 driver.

Image from the wikipedia link,

[image: Network Protocol Driver]

Comment: Can you provide steps for using this driver type? 1 - install database
please continue

Comment: @gstackoverflow First install Oracle. Then configure Oracle. Then connect to Oracle. Use whichever type of driver you prefer. The type-4 is always recommended. The type-3 and 2 drivers are stop-gap solutions for when your platform doesn't have a driver.

Comment: I can use 4-th type)) question about 3-rd type

Comment: How to configure middleware server? question about it.

Comment: Did you understand my question?